# VBS Refresh and Save Data Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a VBS script that when executed it will refresh data in an excel(2013) file. However it is giving an error on

```
xlBook.DisplayAlerts = False
```

The error message states 'object doesn't support this property or method' 'DisplayAlerts'

Here is the VBS script

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSheet
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\"& "Book1.xlsx")
Set xlSheet = xlBook.worksheets.item(1)
xlBook.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook.RefreshAll
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Try `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: that worked, can you post this as an answer and i will accept it?

Comment: Protip: you know you're working with an `Excel.Workbook` object, and you know from the error message that it doesn't have a `DisplayAlerts` member. The next step should have been to google up "Excel VBA DisplayAlerts" (first hit "Application.DisplayAlerts" on MSDN), not ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The fact the error says "Object doesn't support this property or method" tells you that `DisplayAlerts` isn't a property of `xlBook`. Like @Mat'sMug says a quick Google with that knowledge to hand would have sorted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayAlerts` is a property of the `Application` object

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```